# I soldered 2 AAA batteries together in series but am not getting double voltage

Tags: electrical, low-voltage, battery

I'm sure this is rudimentary, but I'm very inexperienced in anything practical with electronics. Would like to try to get a 3volt battery go run some LEDs. I thought I could just take two AAA batteries (1.5v each) and wire them in series to get approximately 3v.

So using some tape and solder I ran a (green) wire from the butt terminal of one battery to the head of the other:

[image: I burned myself surprisingly few times in making this]

However, when I try to test the voltage, I do not get what I expected

[image: Multimeter shows only 1.63v]

I thought hooking batteries together in series should double the voltage? What am I missing?

Comment: Measure each battery individually, you can still  do that with the wires you have added attached to the battery.  I suspect your batteries don't have a full charge.  Your logic is correct.

Comment: @Tyson you are correct thank you, one of the batteries seems near 0

Comment: This is not do-it-yourself home improvement related.

Comment: Soldering to batteries usually isn't good for them.  2AA and 2AAA battery holders are cheap and plentiful on ebay for future projects.

Comment: Thanks @Grant I was just playing around with this, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Measure each battery individually, you can still do that with the wires you have added attached to the battery. I suspect your batteries don't have a full charge. Your logic is correct.